# File recovery from Mac results in random files and extensions – how do I get my data back?

Tags: windows, macos, data-recovery

This Mac hard drive was dying. Someone I knew did a file recovery and got as many files as he could. The program (not sure how it was done, or what program it was) dished out a bunch of folders names such as:

- `DIR56.TOC`
- `DIR55.CUR`
- `DIR54.GPZ`
- `DIR53.GZI`

… and so forth, all the way down to `DIR0.LZH`. Some of the file extensions I *do* understand — like `.JPEG`, or `.MOV` — but most of them are ones I've never heard of. I've googled some of them like `.TOC`, wich stands for "table of contents", but I don't understand how to transfer that data back to the Mac.

Currently, they are on a Windows machine. They are being transfered onto an external hard drive that the Mac can read. It can also see all the files. However, the few that I tested to see if the Mac recognizes them (like `.TOC` and `.CUR`) cannot be opened.

Anyone have any idea as to what I should do? There are some important assignments on there I need to get.

EDIT:
Data transfer was most likely done by: Easy Recover 6 professional  (95% sure, no guarantee)

Comment: Also, I think I may have solved my own problem. 
I noticed there are some file formats like .DOC and such that I believe the mac will see, and most likely the files I need. So I'm guessing these are the only files I should worry about and forget the rest?

Side note: This is a friends machines I'm working on. I don't own macs.

Comment: I guess it would be good to know which software was used to recover the data.

Comment: I added a edit. Thats the best I can say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is due to the recovery tool either grabbing any file (regardless of whether it had been deleted), or grabbing data from unallocated blocks.  Norton's Mac tools pulled tricks like this some decades ago, but I don't know of any tools that do it now.  It may be due to setting the tool to aggressively recover data.

The file names you see are not the original file/folder names - they're just data that may or may not be relevant, or perhaps were deleted in the past.  First, check the named recovered files to see that the data you want is all there.  If some is missing, you can then explore the mystery files by content.  Open them in a text editor, or use the [`file` command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29) to identify what kind of data they are, then change the extensions accordingly.

If you want to understand more about how you could have data from a file without a name, or why you'd get parts of a file but not others, read about [HFS+'s Allocation, Catalog, and Extents Overflow files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus).